# Not able to find location of user in android marshmallow.

Tags: android, location

I have already given the permission through phone settings, so no permission issues. My code works fine with below marshmallow. Also in marshmallow I am able to get location in onLocationChanged() class. but not in onCreate() [only when device GPS in on].

Answer (score -1):

Ask permission at run time. Try this:-

Check this in OnCreate():-

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
            PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
}
```

Override this method:-

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // All good!
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Need your location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: but he is saying that his code works well below marshmallow

Comment: But also he says he enable permission from settings

Comment: I did all these stuffs plus I enabled the permission from yhe phone's settings. I don't understand what's going on. It is working well in Emulator with Jelly Bean.